# Cannot add foreign key constraint - Laravel Migration Error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have multiple migrations but the two which I think are relevant to this question are the 'job' and 'session' migrations.

**Job Migration**

```
    Schema::create('job', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Sessions Migration:**

```
    Schema::create('session', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('job_id');
        $table->boolean('verified')->default(0);
        $table->date('date');
        $table->time('start_time');
        $table->time('end_time');
        $table->string('session_type');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('group');
        $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('job');
    });
```

Now the error I get when I make migration is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `session` add constraint `session_job_id_foreign`
>   foreign key (`job_id`) references `job` (`id`))

Database: MySQL

I don't understand what the issue is here. This approach has always worked for me, even in this current Laravel project.

Comment: Are the migrations in the correct order?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I did create the session migration first and then the job migration. Could that be the issue?

Comment: That's the issue. You try to create a foreign key to a table that doesn't exist. Try renaming the migration files by altering the date.

Comment: Okay, yep that worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the that the job migration comes before session migration

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. Simply incrementing the timestamp to a later date works.

Answer (score 1):

While dealing with `migration` and `foreign key relationship` (parent- child), the sequence defined on the basis of timestamp of migration file so always make sure the `Parent table` migration is created before the `Child table`. This is important because if the parent table doesn't exist means the column which you are referring in the `Child table` is not exist and in that case it will through such errors.

In your case changing the timestamp will solve the problem.